# Xcode archive button disabled

Tags: ios, xcode8, archive, software-distribution

This is not a duplicate question!

I uploaded my new app to App Store successfully and am working on the next version.

Now I want to generate an archive, but the **archive** button is disabled. And yes, the target points to *generic build device*.

What else can cause the problem?

Comment: Can you please upload your Xcode's whole screen shot.

Comment: Did you checked ? stackoverflow.com/questions/36799156/archive-button-grayed-out-in-xcode-7/36799270#36799270

Comment: @Hasya saw this... That wasn't my problem... I posted the solution for others that will come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it. go to "*edit scheme*" and check "*archive*" for your target.

Somehow I've lost the check

[image: check archive]

Answer (score 13):

Select Generic Only Device and make sure the target is correct then the build option will be enabled.[image]